# jQuery - Send HTTP PUT to localhost webserver (Port 80)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

How can I send an HTTP PUT request to my local webserver (localhost on port 80) without google chrome changing the request type to `OPTIONS`?

```
var json = {
    on: false
};
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT"
    , url: "http://localhost/api/newdeveloper/lights/6/state"
    , contentType: 'text/plain'
    , data: JSON.stringify(json)
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

[image]

The webserver sends back:

> Access-control-allow-origin: *

So I guess CORS isn't a problem, is it?

Using XMLHttpRequests results in the same problem:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("PUT", "http://localhost/api/newdeveloper/lights/2/state", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.send("{\"on\": false}");
```

Comment: Do you have cors preflight requests turned on?

Comment: I didn't write the webserver, it's a Philips HUE emulator, so I don't have access to it.

Comment: Any github link to that project?

Comment: https://github.com/SteveyO/Hue-Emulator

Comment: The PUT and similar unsafe request are by default off on the servers. You can also use XmlHttpRequest to check the problem and you really do not need  laboured jQuery to send requests. The native  XmlHttpRequest is easy to use and supported by all modern browsers (Firefox, IE, Edge, Chrome, Safari, Opera and CryOS and more other).

Comment: You can also test your requests (not only PUT, GET, POST but also BROW "extension" (-; ) by F12 mode in firefox. "Network" -> Send any request, modyfi it, and resend. You will see answer with request in this panel.

Comment: The problem is that chrome, for whatever reason, changes my PUT request to OPTIONS, if I disable web-security, everything works fine. Why is Chrome doing this to me :(
I thought jQuery uses XmlHttpRequests internally?